# Ansible "No package matching 'nginx' found available, installed or updated"

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, ansible, yaml, devops

I want to install and run nginx server using ansible on ec2 instance(centOS). But I have following
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8DeA.png)

Output of problem

*fatal: [ec2-user]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "No package matching 'nginx' found available, installed or updated", "rc": 126, "results": ["No package matching 'nginx' found available, installed or updated"]}*

my playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: install updates
      yum: name=* state=latest
    - name: install nginx
      become: yes
      yum: name=nginx state=latest
    - name: starting nginx
      become: yes
      service: name=nginx state=started
```

Comment: Are you able to install nginx manually, Like `yum install ...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nginx is not available in the standard repositories of CentOS. You need first to enable the [EPEL](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/epel/) repo to install nginx.

```yaml
# enable EPEL repo by installing the epel-release package
- name: install EPEL repo
  become: yes
  yum: name=epel-release state=present
```